# passing multiple items in an object as a payload in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an action called fetchRatings, which uses the axios http client to create multiple consts, and then pull data and then manipulate it. I then want to pass all of these consts into an object. The code for this is below:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
headers: { 'x-api-version': 2}
});
const BASE_URL = 'http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Establishments?pageSize=5000&pageNumber=1&LocalAuthorityId='
export const FETCH_RATINGS = 'FETCH_RATINGS';

export function fetchRatings(authorityId) {

  const pass =
  instance.get(`${BASE_URL + authorityId}`).then(function(response) {
    return Math.round(response.data.establishments.reduce(function (n, establishment) {
      return n + (establishment.RatingValue === "Pass");
    }, 0) / response.data.establishments.length * 100)
  })

  const fail =
  instance.get(`${BASE_URL + authorityId}`).then(function(response) {
    return Math.round(response.data.establishments.reduce(function (n, establishment) {
      return n + (establishment.RatingValue === "Improvement Required");
    }, 0) / response.data.establishments.length * 100)
  })

  const exempt =
  instance.get(`${BASE_URL + authorityId}`).then(function(response) {
    return Math.round(response.data.establishments.reduce(function (n, establishment) {
      return n + (establishment.RatingValue === "Exempt");
    }, 0) / response.data.establishments.length * 100)
  })

  return {
    type: FETCH_RATINGS,
    payload: {pass: pass, fail: fail, exempt: exempt}
  };
}
```

I also have a ratings reducer, which looks like this:

```
import { FETCH_RATINGS } from '../actions/fetch_ratings';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_RATINGS:
      return action.payload ;
  }
  return state;
}
```

When I call the action in my code, My props in the React console look like this:

```
Props
dispatch:
fn()
ratings:
{…}
exempt:
Promise{…}
fail:
Promise{…}
pass:
Promise{…}
```

Any idea why I'm not able to push different items into props here? Am I just structuring it incorrectly?

Comment: are you using something for handling the async request in action? like maybe `redux-promise` or `redux-thunk` or something else.

Comment: Yep I'm using redux-promise. If I just use one const here and then just simply put `payload: pass` then it works. It is just having more than one of these that makes it not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redux-promise` will handle only a promise but

```
{
    pass : Promise,
    fail : Promise,
    exempt : Promise,
}
```

is not a promise. You have to convert it to single promise so that `redux-promise` can handle it. I think you need `Promise.all` for this task. Try something like:

```
const payload = Promise.all([ pass, fail, exempt ])
                .then( ([ pass, fail, exempt ]) => {
                   return { pass, fail, exempt }
                });

// now payload will be a single promise and you can pass it on normally.

return {
    type: FETCH_RATINGS,
    payload: payload
};
```

`Promise.all` will convert your multiple promises into single promise and will resolve only if all the promise will resolve, else it will get rejected.

**Reference:** Read more about [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Amazing. Works perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: the answer of [Raghavgarg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439731/raghavgarg) is probably better if you already have logic that depends on your final payload (the one in the reducer) having the same structure as before.

The middle-ware you use for promises probably expects the payload to be a promise, not an object that happens to contain promises.

To solve this you could wrap them all in [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
return {
  type: FETCH_RATINGS,
  payload: Promise.all([pass, fail, exempt])
};
```

Then in your reducer the payload would be an array where the responses will be ordered in the same way as you put them (above).